# How to send @FormUrlEncoded and @Multipart request at the same time using Retrofit lib

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I am writing a client-server Android application. I need to send a file created by user (photo) to server via POST request. The problem is, that when i try to send a file, i can't add a POST Field to my request. Maybe I'm wrong fundamentally, and this operation should be done another way?

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Multipart
@POST("/answer/add-file")
Call<AbstractServerResponse> sendSingleFile(@Query("access-token") String accessToken,
                                            @Query("w") String screenWidth,
                                            @Field("answer_id") Integer answerId,
                                            @Part("file") File fileToUpload);
```

When i try to send files in a multipart way only, i get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSON must start with an array or an object.
```

As I understand, this happends because the body (main part) of the request is empty.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart requests are used when @Multipart is present on the method. Parts are declared using the @Part annotation.
------ from http://square.github.io/retrofit/

I'm using @Multipart in my project like this:

```
@POST("/{action}")//POST 多个文件
@Multipart
public void PostAPI(
    @Path(value = "action", encode = false) String action, 
    @Part("path") TypedFile[] typedFiles, 
    @PartMap Map<String, String> params, 
    Callback<APIResponse> callback);
```

Maybe u can try this：

```
@Multipart
@POST("/answer/add-file")
Call<AbstractServerResponse> sendSingleFile(
    @Query("access-token") String accessToken,
    @Query("w") String screenWidth,
    @Part("answer_id") Integer answerId, 
    @Part("file") File fileToUpload);
```

Comment: When i try to send a request like you suggested, i get an exception.

Comment: @AndreyOlkhovsky, What exception are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both `@FormUrlEncoded` and `@Multipart` on a single method. An ***HTTP*** request can only have **one** `Content-Type` and both of those are content types.